# Embeded youtube video won't play in loop

Tags: javascript, html, video, youtube, embed

I'm trying to play youtube video in loop but it does not work.

```
 <iframe id="music" width="1" height="1"
            src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/jAsSgK3CvO0?playlist=jAsSgK3CvO0&autoplay=1&loop=1">
 </iframe>
```

After once loop, video is freezing and I can't play automatically once again.

Whats I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code works fine on my machine. Please check with other machines too. Also check whether other code conflicting with video playback.

Comment: Okay, I fix that by download music from video and I'm just serving audio html5 :) Thanks for help